# Iesi.Collections (nuget package) is not supported for .NET 2.0 ? Huh?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, iesi-collections

I've just tried adding Iesi.Collections to a .NET 2.0 project and it failed :-

```
PM> Install-Package Iesi.Collections
Successfully installed 'Iesi.Collections 3.2.0.4000'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Iesi.Collections 3.2.0.4000'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Iesi.Collections 3.2.0.4000'. You are trying to install this package into a project that target
s '.NETFramework,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more i
nformation, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Iesi.Collections
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Um, Huh???

I thought the whole idea of Iesi.Collections was to get support for collections that existed in .NET 3.5+++ but not in .NET 2.0 .. so this package is -made- for a .NET 2.0 project? Waaa??

[image]

### Update

I have to target a .NET 2.0 project so I can't update to a 3.5 project. (and if i did that I wouldn't need to use this package...)

Comment: Change the target to 3.5, install, set it back.

Comment: Um .. my project has to target 2.0 .. so that's not possible. I'll update the opening post to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the Iesi.Collections maintained by the NHibernate project is here:
https://github.com/nhibernate/iesi.collections

The current master targets .Net 4 but looking back through the commits you should find the code for the previous version. I don't know if it really depends on .Net 3.5 or if this is just an oversight in the packaging. You might have some success compiling it yourself.

The driving force for this library have been NHibernate's needs, and for that .Net 3.5 didn't help much as MS added HashSet but not ISet. This wasn't rectified until .Net 4.